# What is the regular expression for all bit strings with even number of 0's?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-language, regular-expressions

What is the regular expression for all bit strings with even number of 0's?

Would it be: 0*(1*01*0)*

And if so can you explain why, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see the comments in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3153121/expand-the-regular-expression-01) for a guide on how to ask good questions.

Comment: If helpful, the regular expression in your most recent edit matches "zero or more $0$s, followed by zero or more instances of (zero or more $1$s, followed by one $0$, followed by zero or more $1$s, followed by a zero)". Hence, all of the following would match: `0`, `0100`, `00001011011101110`, `010101010`, `110110`, `100`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the regular expression you posted is not valid.

Assuming that strings are comprised of $\{0,1\}$, one possible regular expression would be $1^*(01^*01^*)^*$. This expression matches any number of leading $1$s, followed by any number of *pairs* of $0$s, where each pair can be interlaced with any number of $1$s.

This visualization may help:

$$\underbrace{11111111}_{\text{1*}}\underbrace{0110111}_{\text{01*01*}}\underbrace{01111110}_{\text{01*01*}}\underbrace{0011111111}_{\text{01*01*}}$$

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703316/regular-expression-for-bit-strings-with-even-number-of-1s) equivalent question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, but then should you also concatenate 1* on the end of that to have any number of 1's following?

Comment: @Pat That would be superfluous. See my edit.

Comment: @Pat If my answer suffices, might you consider [accepting it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/) by [clicking on the greyed out check mark](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/)?